# How to get current changesetid on tfs build server?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm need to include changesetid in assemblyversions on TFS build server. I have created powershell script that updates [AssembliVersion] attributes is all assemblyinfo.cs.

How can I get current changeset for a folder in tfs?

currently I have something like this:

```
function GetLatestChangeset{
    Param([string]$projectDir)

    $changesetId = Get-TfsItemHistory $projectDir -Recurse -version:W | % ChangesetId | sort -Descending
    if ($changesetId.Count -eq 0){
        return 0
    }
    return $changesetId[0]
}
```

but it returns latest changeset id, not the one being built

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new build system you should be able to use the environment variable $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION 
see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables

For XAML builds you could use TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION environment variable : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this within the scope of a gated check-in and the change has not yet been committed, there will be no 'current' changeset. We do something similar, but after the build has been committed and at that point then simply query the buildserver to get the latest build as below ;

```
var buildDetail = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
    var vcserver = buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    var queryHistoryResult = vcserver
                                .QueryHistory(versionControlPath, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, 
                                              RecursionType.Full, null, null, null, 1, 
                                              true, false)
                                .Cast<Changeset>()
                                .ToList();

    if (!queryHistoryResult.Any())
    {
        throw new ChangesetNotFoundException("GetLatestChangesetActivity: No current changeset available.");
    }

    var changeset = queryHistoryResult.First();
```

which looks pretty much the same as your code.

Comment: I do NOT do it within scope of gated checkin. The problem is, that when this script executes, there may be newer changesets as the one being build, already

Answer (score 0):

To get the associated changeset summaries from the specified build, you can use [InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339559(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: could be, but I still don't know how to use it. How to get instance of IBuildDetail?